# Spring Amqp Consumer pauses after running for sometime

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, consumer, spring-rabbit

We have a 2 node RabbitMQ cluster with Ha-all policy. We use Spring AMQP in our application to talk to RabbitMQ. Producer part is working fine, but consumer works for some time and pauses. Producer and consumer are running as different applications. More information on Consumer part.

- we use `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` with `ChannelAwareMessageListener`, use Manual `ack` mode and default `prefetch(1)`
- In our application we create queue (on-demand) and add it to the listener
- When we started with 10 `ConcurrentConsumers` and 20 `MaxConcurrentConsumers`, consumption happens for around 15 hours and pauses. This situation happens within 1 hour when we increase the `MaxConcurrentConsumers` to 75.

On RabbitMQ UI, we see channels with 3/4 un`ack`ed messages on the channel tab when this situation occurs, until then it just have 1 un`ack`ed message.

Our thread dump was similar to [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/amqp/724928-consumers-stops-consuming-no-exception-or-warnings). But having heartbeat set to 60 did not help improve this situation.

Most of the thread dump has the following message. If required I will attach the whole thread dump. Let me know if I am missing any setup which might cause the consumer to pause?

```
"pool-6-thread-16" #86 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f4db09cb000 nid=0x3b33 waiting on condition [0x00007f4ebebec000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007b9930b68> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.put(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:350)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$InternalConsumer.handleDelivery(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:660)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:144)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

More Info
We dynamically add and remove queues to SimpleMessageListenerContainer and we suspect this is causing some problem, because every time we add or remove a queue from the listener, all the BlockingQueueConsumer are removed and created again. Do you think if this can cause this problem?

Comment: You need to post the full thread dump someplace, probably not here because it's too big; maybe something like pastebin or a github gist. Most likely the container thread is stuck in your code someplace.

Comment: @GaryRussell: http://pastebin.com/UrBLfn2C is the paste-bin that contains complete thread dump.

Comment: The thread dump looks good - all the container threads are waiting in `nextMessage()` so it looks like your current theory is correct - something in the network has silently dropped the connection - some routers do that for idle connections. Setting the requested heartbeat should keep the connection alive - you will need to use a network monitor (tcpdump, wireshark etc) to figure it out.

Comment: @GaryRussell : we tried with the heartbeat option but it was of no use(Though we did not try with any network monitor as such) and we also don't have idle connections we have traffic continuously. I have added some more info to the question, which we think might be the cause.

Comment: Hmmm - that's a possibility - the thread in your question is trying to insert a message; it looks like the queue is full, but perhaps the old consumer has gone away already - it shouldn't happen because we cancel the consumer before stopping it but there might be a race condition. Please open a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP) and we'll take a look.

Comment: And share, please, in that JIRA a Spring AMQP version you use.

Comment: @GaryRussell: Created https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-621. Feel free to modify the ticket attributes.

Comment: @ArtemBilan: Please see my above comment to Gary Russell

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is somewhere downstream in the target listener.

Look, `prefetch(1)` cause this:

```
this.queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Delivery>(prefetchCount);
```

And further if we don't poll that queue what we have here?

```
BlockingQueueConsumer.this.queue.put(new Delivery(consumerTag, envelope, properties, body));
```

Right, parking on lock.

Answer (score 0):

AMQP-621 is now merged to master; we will release 1.6.1.RELEASE in the next few days.